# initWithAppID not using native Facebook login with iOS SDK 3.1.1

Tags: ios6, facebook-ios-sdk

I have 2 iOS apps using the same Facebook APP ID.

The first works great with the new native Facebook Login.

While integrating with the paid version, I was following [this guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/share-appid-across-multiple-apps-ios-sdk/) to share app ID between both apps.

**The problem:** For some reason the following code isn't using the native Facebook login, but opens Safari for a web login instead.

```
BOOL result = NO;

FBSession *session = [[FBSession alloc] initWithAppID:nil
                                          permissions:permissions
                                      urlSchemeSuffix:@"paid"
                                   tokenCacheStrategy:nil];

if (allowLoginUI || (session.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded)) {
    [FBSession setActiveSession:session];
    [session openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
         [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
     }];
    result = session.isOpen;
}

return result;
```

I was double checking that I was logged in with my Facebook account at the iPhone's settings window.

No clue at Facebook docs about this.

Have they released an unfinished/bugged SDK?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use the **openWithBehavior:completionHandler:** variant for opening the session and explicitly specify **FBSessionLoginBehaviorUseSystemAccountIfPresent** for the behavior.